# AzureDevOps Pipeline CICD No Objects Found

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks, cicd

I  use Azure DevOps for CI/CD. From the previous week, I have done nothing about my pipeline. I use .net6 ACR and AKS. Today I made a release and the pipeline failed on Kubectl apply task.Here is the deployment.yml and error message
The manifests and deployment are already in the artifacts 100%. Here is the path to the artifacts in apply stage

File Path:

> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**_Service.Payment/Manifests/qa/deployment.yml**

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: payment-service-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: payment-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: payment-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: payment-service
        image: service.azurecr.io/paymentservice
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "200m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Error from Azure:

> 2022-12-13T10:51:29.5634198Z [command]/opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.7.0/x64/kubectl apply -n qa -f /home/vsts/work/r1/a/**_Service.Payment/Manifests/qa/deployment.yml** -o json
> 2022-12-13T10:51:29.7227832Z error: no objects passed to apply
> 2022-12-13T10:51:29.7317807Z ##[error]error: no objects passed to apply
> 2022-12-13T10:51:29.7327285Z commandOutput
> 2022-12-13T10:51:30.0483666Z ##[error]The process '/opt/hostedtoolcache/kubectl/1.7.0/x64/kubectl' failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I had resolve the issue after removing these lines:

```
- task: CopyFiles@1
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Manifests'
      Contents: '**'
      TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Manifests'
      OverWrite: true
  - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
    inputs:
      PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/Manifests'
      ArtifactName: 'Manifests'
      publishLocation: 'Container'
```

and add these:

```
- upload: Manifests
    artifact: Manifests
    displayName: 'Upload Artifact: Manifests'
```

It is very strange why the PublishBuildArtifacts@1 makes yml files in Manifests like directories but the second just upload makes them like files. So the problem was that files were like directories.